# jquery ajax call empty querystring

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http

So, I am using jquery to make an ajax call to a php script on my server.

For some reason I cannot figure out, however, there is no querystring sent. Using var_dump() on the $_GET object shows that it is an empty string, and Chrome's network activity developer tool indicates no string is sent.

```
$.ajax({
            "url":"../script/content.php",
            "settings": {
                "dataType":"html",
                "type":"GET",
                "data":{
                    "id":$(this).prop('id')
                }
            }
        }).done( function(msg) {
            //$('#debug').html(msg);
            $('#dialog').html(msg);
            $('#dialog').load(function() {
                $('#close').click(function() {
                    $('#over').fadeOut(fadeTime);
                });
                if ($('#unique') > 0) {
                    $('#unique').load(function(){
                        $('#over').fadeIn(fadeTime);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#over').fadeIn(fadeTime);
                }
            });             
        });
```

I had tried the ajax call without the quotes where they weren't necessary before hand, and the result was the same... I just put those in because I thought it might be the problem... though I think that in such notation the quotes don't make a difference unless one of the field values is supposed to be a string.

Is there anything clear in that code which might cause a querystring not to be sent? I guess there is a problem with my syntax... I just can't see it.

The #dialog load callback seems to never be called, either... but I guess that is another question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try the same script with Firefox. I had this exact same problem and it worked on Firefox fine.

Comment: instead of using `.prop` but try with `.attr` what do you get with it?

Comment: `this` inside `$.ajax` is not a DOM element. Define the ID value before `$.ajax` and pass that variable in to the data object

Comment: before the $.ajax gets called do a console.inf( $(this).prop('id') ); it will show you if your string contains anything and I do not see the point for you to define "dataType":"html" use the default dataType (just remove it)

Comment: @charlietfl A combination of your suggestion and roshan's answer seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: should not have required changing data to a query string. Passing an object is actually easier and will be converted to url search string for you by `$.ajax`. Also leads to less problems, and less code using object for data....especially when dealing with larger objects that may already exist in application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    //The link we are accessing with params
    url:'http://example.com/script/content.php'
    + '?id='
    + $(this).prop('id'),
    // The type of request.
    type: "get",
    //The type of data that is getting returned.
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
    //something here
    },
    success: function( strData ){
    //something here
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, the PHP script picks up the id. Thanks. However, I now have a new problem. Neither the success nor the error callbacks are being made.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It works. I still had everything in the settings: {} object, which I guess is wrong/isn't necessary...

Comment: Hey can you use JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/, you can test your Javascript here. Also if possible share your website link.

Comment: In future, I will do that. The problem is fixed now, though. Thanks.

Comment: step backwards in my opinion changing a data object to manually creating query string when jQuery will do it automatically for you

Comment: @charlietfl I will give it a shot with a data object instead.