# How to pass dynamic query string from php via ajax and result will be display in pop up box

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I need to pass php dynamic query strings using ajax and the response will be shown in modal box or pop up box. Here I give the set of codes which I tried. Here I want to pass the dynamic urls and shows the result from the request page.

```
foreach ($files1 as $file)
{
$url='http://localhot/list1/'.$file;
$var1=$var1.'<div class="submit2"><li><a  href="/localhost/list2.php?var='.$urls.'" id="test">'."submit".'</a></li></div>';

}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("#test").click(function(e)
    {

       var link=$(this);
       e.preventDefault();
       $.get("/localhost/list2.php?var="+link.attr('id'),function(response){
               $("#ajaxresponse div").fadeOut("fast", function()
               {


             $("#ajaxresponse div").html(response).fadeIn();


});   
       });             
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no i did not get any error

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862109/jquery-ajax-call-empty-querystring/15862289?noredirect=1#comment22642458_15862289

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are facing ?

Comment: In that PHP foreach loop, multiple 'test' id will be created. Actually, You are checking the click event for one particular id (#test). Can't you make it dynamic?

Comment: You can't use the same ID `test` for multiple `div`s on the same page, kind of defeats the purpose of using an ID.

Comment: hi i need to pass the url for  the particular file as a querystring.so the $file listout the file from the  directiory and i add it into the atag.so here i need to send the url as query string (the urls are submitted to another site) using jquery ajax and get the response from the request page

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Just an example!

```
    <div id="ajaxresponse"><h2>Ajax Response</h2></div>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <?php
    $files1=array("a","b","c","d","e");
    foreach ($files1 as $key=>$file)
    {
    $url='http://localhot/list1/'.$file;
    $var1=$url.'<div class="submit2"><li><a href="#" id="test_'.$key.'" onClick="clickAct('.$key.')">'."submit".'</a></li></div>';
    echo $var1;
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function clickAct(vals)
        {
           $.get("list2.php?var="+vals,function(response){

                        $("#ajaxresponse").html(response).fadeIn();


           });             

    } 
    </script>
```

list2.php

```
    <?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    echo "<h2>Parameter was ".$var."</h2>";
    ?>
```